# Why it's redirecting to localhost://3000 while passing an url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

"I created a site which provides sign in and sign up page using devise gem. I'm trying to reach [localhost:3000/users/sign_in](https://localhost://3000/users/sign_up) this path. But it's redirecting to [localhost://3000](https://localhost://3000)

"This is for ruby 2.5 and rails 6.0. I tried some possible ways like clearing cookies, restarting server. But still I'm facing the same issue."

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

   #fields for sign_up page

<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

"I'm expecting to get the sign_in page, but it redirects to root url"

Logs

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-08-21 13:22:56 +0530
   (0.3ms)  SET NAMES utf8mb4,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
   (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms | Allocations: 9317)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-08-21 13:22:56 +0530
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering /home/parvathy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /home/parvathy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (Duration: 7.0ms | Allocations: 315)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 13.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1772)
```

Comment: can we have a look to your controller? How do you configure routing to users/sign_in in /config/routes.rb?

Comment: `devise_for: users` this alone I have in routes.rb @PietroAllievi

Comment: Can you add the logs to see the redirection please

Comment: We can see that the `require_no_authentication` method redirects the user. This devise before_action disable the required authentication on new actions. Have you customized it?

Comment: Actually I didn't customize anything. I just created a new app and created models, views and controllers using devise. It generated everything. I'm trying to execute those automatically generated routes. but those routes are redirecting to root url. whenever I clear my cookies and caches it works for the 1st time.

Comment: If it works the first time when you navigate to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in and you sign then you can't go to that url because you are signed in.

Comment: yeah I got it!! thank you so much @Hackman

Comment: Np @ParvathyManivannan have a good day

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This boils down to a malformed URL.

> > localhost://3000

Is not correctly formed.

> > localhost:3000/blah

Means localhost at port 3000, directory blah

The colon has to prepend the port number.

The protocol decorator :// is for http:// https:// ftp:// etc

http is the protocol, which defaults to port 80 for http and 443 for https, but can be specified as we do here by putting it after the top level domain.

> http://localhost:3000

Should solve your problem.